# Good way to handle exceptions in this case (Selenium WebDriver-Using Java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm having some issues writing a test for exception handling in Selenium Webdriver (using Java). I'm trying to do the following: Click through a series of menu items one by one and if there are any sorts of error messages (windows) that pop up, then I need to throw an exception to fail the test. However, throughout the application, the same class (for example, x-window-header), I had to use a for statement to find the specific title text.

Below is an example of what I have so far (I'm trying to use a nested try-catch block to do this.) Is there a better way of implementing this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    File file = new File("C:/Program Files/Selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    driver.get("http://ap-apbase-d002/Ecx.Web/Account/Login/?ReturnUrl=%2fEcx.Web%2f");
    WebElement element;
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    element.sendKeys("Jh");
    element = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    element.sendKeys("1");
    element.submit();
    WebElement homeFrame = (new WebDriverWait(driver,30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("pnCenter_IFrame")));
    driver.switchTo().frame("pnCenter_IFrame");
    WebElement myHomeLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("My Projects")));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Projects")).click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame("pnCenter_IFrame");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    //parent try block, this blocks is used to click through all menu items
    try{
        WebElement UniversalInboxLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Universal Inbox")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Universal Inbox")).click();
        WebElement MyProjectsLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("My Projects")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Projects")).click();
        WebElement AllProjectsLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("All Projects")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Projects")).click();
        WebElement MyTeamLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("My Team")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Team")).click();
        WebElement WOTTaxFormLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("WOT Tax Form")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("WOT Tax Form")).click();
        WebElement MyDraftsLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("My Drafts")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Drafts")).click();
        WebElement MyArchivesLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("My Archives")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("My Archives")).click();
        WebElement RetrieveLink = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Retrieve")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Retrieve")).click();
        //Child try block, this block is used to look for this element in each frame, not sure how to implement correctly.
        try{
            List <WebElement> AppbaseErrorWindow = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".x-window-header"));
            for (WebElement item : AppbaseErrorWindow) {
                if (item.getText().contains("Request Failure")) {
                    //Do Nothing, not sure what to do here
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception is found here: " + e);
        }
        System.exit(0);
        driver.quit();
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("All is OK.");
    }
    System.out.println("Normal behavior");
 }
```

I was told to use the following format when doing my test:

```
main
    test suite
    try{
        test1();
        test2();
    }catch(e){
        //show the error
        exit
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this more a question for Code Review?

Comment: You could build a list of buttons, then in your "try" block, using a "for" loop to go through your list of buttons instead of running them one by one. This will shorten your code by a bit.